# Entity Framework performance problems

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

I'm having a problem where the below query is taking around 700ms to execute. It's in a loop and gets called 100+ times so it's taking forever.

Model:

```
public class ReleaseDates
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string AlternateSource { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
public async Task<List<ReleaseDates>> GetReleaseDatesAsync(string movieName)
{
    return await Db.ReleaseDates.Where(x => x.MovieName == movieName && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AlternateSource)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Any suggestions how to speed this up?

Comment: Take it out of a loop and change it so there is only one query to get everything? You can keep appending where conditions without enumerating it

Comment: The table is very large 10,000's of data. So grabbing everything I would have thought to be a bad idea?

Comment: Maybe you should use a stored procedure to do the join and get the data you need the return instead of looping and passing in movieName in 1 by 1

Comment: How about pagination?

Comment: Use results caching (also known as "second-level caching"), you keep the results of queries in a local cache. When issuing a query, you first see if the results are available locally before you query against the store.

Comment: Hard to say without your loop code but assuming you call it multiple times to create some sort of groups then...call it once (with all allowed conditions) and (before calling `ToListAsync()` group items with `.GroupBy(x => x.MovieName)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the loop. That's the problem. You're sending a lot of queries to database.

Store all the movie names that you're searching for in a list and do a contains there.

```
public async Task<List<ReleaseDates>> GetReleaseDatesAsync(List<string> movieNames)
{
    //movie names that you're searching for - movieNames

    return await Db.ReleaseDates.Where(x => movieNames.Contains(x.MovieName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AlternateSource)).ToListAsync();

}
```

If you want to get the release dates for "Ant Moon", "GodZippa", "SuperWan", your list will contain these strings and this is it.

Some further reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

Comment: Yeah stupid of me, when trying to work something out I always end up with tunnel vision. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a index on your movie name field. Also, catch the query through profiler and exec it in Sql Management Studio with Show Plan enabled. It will give you some insights to optimize the query performance.

Comment: sorry, new to EF, how would i create an index?

Comment: Do it directly on Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: I'm using a code first approach, Can it not be done via the model or any EF configuration?

Comment: I believe you can create indices if you're using EF 6.1. If you're using a version lower than 6.1, you'll have to do it manually. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index